# Calling item from array in a model Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode8

I'm trying to get an item (item.event_date) from my CoverModel into another Model called PhotosModel, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction or demonstrate. I can get said information into an array in a viewcontroller but not a model for some reason.

I tried

```
PhotosModel.eventDate = items.event_date
```

but with no luck.

CollectionView:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)


    let item: CoverModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! CoverModel

    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailCollectionViewController") as! DetailCollectionViewController

  // PhotosModel.eventDate = items.event_date (Not Working)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)

}
```

PhotosModel:

```
class PhotosModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {

        //properties

        weak var delegate: PhotosProtocol!

        var eventDate = String()
        var data = Data()

        let urlPath: String = "http://www.britanniaclub.co.uk/app_calls/britalbum.php?eventdate=\(eventDate)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare an **instance** of your PhotosModel class. Then, set the `eventDate` parameter on that instance.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.row)

    let item: CoverModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! CoverModel

    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailCollectionViewController") as! DetailCollectionViewController

    let newPhotos = PhotosModel()  // Create the instance
    newPhotos.eventDate = items.event_date  // Set the parameter

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set instance property directly on class.

```
PhotosModel.eventDate = items.event_date
```

if you are just interested in date. Access it like this

```
 let eventDate = items.event_date
```

Comment: Sorry I should have explained a little better. I'm trying to push items.event_date of the selected cell in the collectionview to urlPath in PhotosModel. I can't reference PhotosModel eventDate from the collectionview, what would be the best to to do this?